# Why string copied by strcpy() after returning from function is null in C

Tags: c, function, return-value, string-literals, storage-duration

I have the following test:

```
char* test1()
{
    char* string = "test 1\n";
    printf("In function: %s", string);
    return string;
}

char* test2()
{
    char* string[10];
    strcpy(string, "test 2\n");
    printf("In function: %s", string);
    return string;
}

int main()
{

    printf("After returned: %s", test1());
    printf("After returned: %s", test2());
}
```

output:

```
In function: test 1
After returned: test 1
In function: test 2
After returned: (null)
```

It seems that in `test2()` `string` is printed correctly, but after it was returned it become `null`.

How to properly return a string constructed via `strcpy()` and what is the reason for this behaviour?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're returning a pointer that's invalid after the function returns. Can't do that.

Comment: ```char* string[10]``` is not a 10 chars array, but is a 10 pointers array. Anyway, it is a local block of fixed memory, which is discarded after return

Comment: If you turn on warnings, gcc at least should tell you you're doing several things wrong here.

Comment: Local variables, including arrays, have a life-time of the block they are defined in. In yout `test2` function, the life-time of `string` will end when the function returns. The pointer you return (which is wrong as mentioned above) will not be valid.

Comment: And literal strings are really (read-only) arrays of characters with a life-time of the whole program. With `char* string = "test 1\n";` you make the variable `string` point to the first element of such an array. Since the array have a life-time of the whole program, the pointer the function returns will never be invalid.

Comment: this is a very interesting behaviour of c. so I cannot refactor a code that constructs a string. thank you for your comments

Comment: You can refactor code, but not like that. The usual way is to pass the buffer pointer and length to the function.

Comment: @AbrahamZsomborNagy you can refactor C code, but just like any other modern programming language, objects have live times that you need to respect. What you're doing there is simply introducing a fundamental bug.

Comment: pointer to char inside a function is allocated on the stack frame for that function, use the `malloc` function call to return a string, for yourself to observe the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `test1` returns a pointer to a string literal

```
char* test1()
{
    char* string = "test 1\n";
    printf("In function: %s", string);
    return string;
}
```

String literals have static storage duration. That is the string literal used in the function `test1` stays alive after exiting the function.

The function `test2`

```
char* test2()
{
    char* string[10];
    strcpy(string, "test 2\n");
    printf("In function: %s", string);
    return string;
}
```

does not make sense and invokes undefined behavior.

For starters, the function `strcpy()` expects its first argument to have type `char *` while the expression `string` used as the first argument has the type `char **` after implicit conversion of the array designator to pointer to its first element. And the conversion specifier `%s` used in the call of the function `printf()` also expects an argument of the type `char *` but is supplied an argument of the type `char **`.

And again the function return type is `char *` while the function returns an expression of the type `char **` as explained above.

And using the returned pointer to the local array `string` with automatic storage duration after exiting the function invokes undefined behavior because the array is not alive after exiting the function. So the returned pointer is  invalid.

Comment: sorry, `char* string[10]` is a typo, it meant to be `char string[10]`

Comment: @AbrahamZsomborNagy It does not matter because in any case the function returns a pointer to a local array that will not be alive after exiting the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first piece of code uses a pointer to return a value, which stays intact after the function finishes executing, and can still be accessed after function 1 has finished executing, however, the second piece of code tries to return a value but when it finishes executing, it cannot return that value because the string does not exist in memory anymore (for function 2) since it is a character array and not pointer, hence why you get null. Also in function 2, character arrays are defined as `char arr[] = "";`. There is no requirement for the `*` there, else it gets treated as a pointer to an array of type `char` and not a character array.